# Set riddle identification

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So this thing occurred to me in a dream, and I'd like to ask if any of you have seen it before in a more formal context.

```
Let A0, B0, C0... be sets.
A':=A0
B':=A'∆B0 [symmetric difference]
C':=B'∆C0
...
Z':=Y'∆Z0 [or any other finite number of sets]

A1:=A'∩B0
B1:=B'∩C0
...
Y1:=Y'∩Z0

A'':=A1
B'':=A''∆B1
...
Y'':=X''∆Y1

A2:=A''∩B1
B2:=B''∩C1
...
X2:=X'∩Y1
and so on, forming a chained pyramid of sorts.
What is the last set of each difference chain? [Ie Z', Y'', X''' etc.]
```

---

I can see that the chaining of the symmetric differences yields elements which appear an odd number of times, and suspect that later layers might behave as the binary representation of the number of appearances.

---

Edit: An example.

```
A0:={1,2,3,4,5}
B0:={2,6,7,8}
C0:={2,9}
D0:={2,7,9}

=>
A'={1,2,3,4,5}
B'={1,3,4,5,6,7,8}
C'={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
D'={1,3,4,5,6,8}

A1={2}
B1={}
C1={2,7,9}

A''={2}
B''={2}
C''={7,9}

A2={}
B2={2}

A'''={}
B'''={2}

A3={}

=> D'={1,3,4,5,6,8}, C''={7,9}, B'''={2}
```

Comment: Its not clear what you are asking. Are there a finite number of sets $A,B,C, \dots$ or is it an infinite sequence of sets?
Also, do I understand you correctly that your question is how $A'',B'',\dots$ look?

Comment: I think finite. And I meant the last set per each layer; For example, if my sets are A, B, C, D, then what are D', C'', B'''.

Comment: How is $B'''$ defined? this is not clear from your question. Also you can edit the question to improve it.

Comment: Oh, I see it now... phrased it incorrectly, there were actually supposed to be two "series". Essentially, the difference going sideways and the intersection going upwards. I've added an example to clarify - how's that?